# iPhone UISwitch react with another UISwitch

Tags: iphone, xcode, boolean, uiswitch

I've read all about UISwitches already but I cannot seem to figure them out in my situation.
I have 2 UISwitches. In order for my code to work only one of them can be ON. How would I accomplish this?

So far i've tried...

**MyClass.h**

```
-(IBAction)sufSwitchChanged:(id)sender;
```

**MyClass.m**

```
-(IBAction)preSwitchChanged:(id)sender {
UISwitch *whichSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
BOOL setting = whichSwitch.isOn;
[newsPre setOn:setting animated:YES];
[techPre setOn:setting animated:YES];
}
```

....which worked but it made both switches ON or OFF. I just need to figure out how to prevent them from both being ON at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Register both UISwitches to observe *UIControlEventValueChanged* notifications against the the other switch.  Something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { // or whatever method is appropriate
    UISwitch *a = <# initialize a #>;
    UISwitch *b = <# initialize b #>;

    [a addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleB:)   
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 

    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleA:)   
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 
}

- (IBAction)toggleA:(id)sender {
    [b setOn:NO animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)toggleB:(id)sender {
    [a setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

You can also set this relationship up in Interface Builder.

Comment: This looks like a solid answer. +1

Comment: This doesn't say anything to the real problem that even when the relationship are set up (he is reading a book, same a me, it's done in IB builder) it doesn't work. You are giving a nice comment on how to set those relationships up and how to listen to events. But not the core question.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how you are setting both switches to the same value here:

```
[newsPre setOn:setting animated:YES];
[techPre setOn:setting animated:YES];
```

You want to check which one is the sender and then set the other one to the opposite of `setting`. To do so, you will need to set a tag on each switch, or perhaps subclass it. For more information on detecting which switch is which, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559720/handling-multiple-uiswitch-controls-in-a-table-view-without-using-tag-property), which has some good information.