# Multiple UISwitch items in one UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiswitch, ibaction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling multiple UISwitch controls in a table view without using tag property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559720/handling-multiple-uiswitch-controls-in-a-table-view-without-using-tag-property)

Well i want to ask how can i configure 7 UISwitches on one UIview? I place the switches with interface builder and then i want to manage them through code. What is the best way of managing this. Here is my .h so far

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface searchEditViewController : UIViewController{

    UISwitch *switchOne;
    UISwitch *switchTwo;
    UISwitch *switchFor;
    UISwitch *switchFive;
    UISwitch *switchSix;
    UISwitch *switchSeven;


}

@property(nonatomic,retain)UISwitch *switchOne;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UISwitch *switchTwo;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UISwitch *switchThree;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UISwitch *switchFour;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UISwitch *switchFive;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UISwitch *switchSix;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UISwitch *switchSeven;
-(IBAction)toggleButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

I want to make one action method toggleButtonPressed that will take care the seven of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one action for all `UISwitch` objects (I guess this is `toggleButtonPressed`). In this method now you can know which UISwitch was triggered:

```
-(IBAction)toggleButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    UISwitch *switchObj = (UISwitch*)sender;
    if (switchObj == self.switchOne){
        // do stuff
    }

    if (switchObj == self.switchTwo){
        // do stuff
    }

//    switch(switchObj.tag){
//        case 1:
//            // do stuff
//            break;
//        case 2:
//            // do stuff
//            break;
//    }
}
```

---

Edit. You can set `tag` property to some value (from 1 to 7) and change `if-statement` to `switch-case`.

Comment: how can do that with switch case? how can i get the tag value the above code doesn't work. I've placed tag values from one to seven through interface builder!

Comment: @MpampinosHolmens, i have updated answer. uncomment switch block if you would like to use it

Comment: thanks for the code but i get this error          [searchEditViewController toggleButtonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc291030
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

Comment: OK fixed it sorry man for the delay, just interface builder shit

Answer (score 1):

@beryllium, your way does work but you might want to try something a little more elegant.

Instead, tag each switch and then instead of if-then use switch-case as you appear to have commented out.

Here's an example, note that kUIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge is actually a constant I created and assigned a value `#define kUIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge 1`

```
- (IBAction)setSpinnerType:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    // switch based on tag value
    // turn other two switches off
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case kUIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge:
            self.spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
            [sender setOn:YES animated:YES];
            [self.whiteSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
            [self.graySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
            break;
        case kUIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite:
            self.spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
            [self.whiteLargeSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
            [sender setOn:YES animated:YES];
            [self.graySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
            break;
        case kUIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray:
            self.spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
            [self.whiteLargeSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
            [self.whiteSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
            [sender setOn:YES animated:YES];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If you want to do it your way, that's OK but again less optimal. However if you do, the code:

```
UISwitch *switchObj = (UISwitch*)sender;
    if (switchObj == self.switchOne){
```

is redundant. instead you can wrote the following:

```
-(IBAction)toggleButtonPressed:(UISwitch *)sender{
    // UISwitch *switchObj = (UISwitch*)sender;
    if (sender == self.switchOne){
        // do stuff
    }
```

I hope that helps.

I created an app to test UIActivityIndicatorView styles on different coloured backgrounds and it uses sliders and switches. Here the url if anyone wants to see the app with IB components:

https://github.com/asadquraishi/UIActivityIndicatorView-Test